# Add title, post content, and category like add_post_meta and update_post_meta

Tags: categories, php, title, actions, description

How can I update/add a new title, post content, and category to a post with hard PHP code similar to add_post_meta(), update_post_meta()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [`wp_update_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post), found in wp-includes/post.php:

```
// Update post 42
$post = array();
$post['ID'] = 42;
$post['post_category'] = array( ... );
$post['post_content' ] = 'This is the updated content.';
$post['post_title' ] = 'This is the updated title.';

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post( $post );
```

Comment: And [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), as the name suggests ;)